# Orange Pi does not run from SDcard and get FF errors (but it works using integrated memory)

Tags: linux, usb, debugging

I recently purchased Orange Pi 2G-IoT. I bought a class 10 8gb sd card. According to the instructions of the oranges, I loaded Ubuntu onto the card. I connect to a PC via a CP2102 USB-UART converter. The port opens correctly, I used the speed of 921600. The power supply for the orange is good, it produces the necessary current. First I connect the converter, then I supply power to the orange. In response I get:

[image]

```
FF FF FF FF
FF FF FD FF
```

…
No more replies come

At Putty I get same results.

I tried without connecting TX from the PC side, everything is the same. I also tried different OS and SD cards. When loading from the built-in memory, it gives the same result.
Also try different COM boud rate.
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: how did you connect the USB to serial converter? ... what do you expect to see in the serial output?

Comment: Hi jsotola. I connect through a usb-uart converter with a logic level of 3.3 volts. gnd-gnd, rx-tx, tx-rx. When I turn it on via the SD card, debugging should occur through the rx and tx pins. but the board sends packets with FF and nothing else.